# How to prevent parallax Image zooming in

Tags: html, css

I have been working on the parallax effect on my page. No matter what i have tried, the image is getting zoomed in when i apply the background properties for the image. I do not want to crop the image but want to fit the div without the zoom effect displaying on desktop version.
I have seen apples website having the parallax effect with the image displaying properly on the div.
You can check it here on their website : https://www.apple.com/education/k12/

```css
.parallax {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.z1 {
  background-image: url('http://cdn.wccftech.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/The-Legend-of-Zelda-Wii-U-1.jpg');
  height: 30rem;
}
.z2 {
  background-image: url('http://cdn.idigitaltimes.com/sites/idigitaltimes.com/files/2016/05/05/legend-zelda-wii-u-nx-nintendo.jpg');
  height: 25rem;
}
.z3 {
  background-image: url('https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/the_legend_of_zelda_windows_elf_character_link_22308_1920x1080.jpg');
  height: 40rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax z1"></div>
<div class="parallax z2"></div>
<div class="parallax z3"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "zoom effect"?

Comment: Image is getting stretched. If you remove attachment property then the image looks fine. Can i achieve the same behaviour for attachment: fixed property also ?

Comment: But there is no zoom effect in your stack snippet. It looks like it is working as expected...